# dplyr's rowwise + replace_NAs: replacing NAs in multiple columns with value from other column

Tags: r, dplyr

I am interested in replacing all NAs in a row with a reference value from that same row. The following code works, but too slowly for my actual use case:

```
df = data.frame(ref = c(1,3,4,2,5), var1 = c(NA,3,4,2,1), var2 = c(1,3,NA,5,5))
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  ref_value = as.character(df$ref[i])
  df[i,] = df[i,] %>% mutate_all(replace_na, replace = ref_value) }
```

I tried to speed up the process with the following modification and got the error below.

```
df = data.frame(ref = c(1,3,4,2,5), var1 = c(NA,3,4,2,1), var2 = c(1,3,NA,5,5))
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate_all(replace_na, replace = ref)
```

error:

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `ref`.
x Replacement for `data` is length 2, not length 1
ℹ Input `ref` is `(function (data, replace, ...) ...`.
ℹ The error occured in row 1.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `coalesce`.  Loop over the 'var' columns and use `coalesce` with the looped column and 'ref', so that wherever there is `NA`, it gets replaced by the corresponding element from 'ref', while the other non-NA element remain as such

```
library(dplyr) #>= 1.0.0
df %>% 
     mutate(across(starts_with('var'), ~ coalesce(., ref)))
#   ref var1 var2
#1   1    1    1
#2   3    3    3
#3   4    4    4
#4   2    2    5
#5   5    1    5
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also works:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(c(var1:var2),~ ifelse(is.na(.), ref, .)))
```

Output:

```
  ref var1 var2
1   1    1    1
2   3    3    3
3   4    4    4
4   2    2    5
5   5    1    5
```